# Infinite Series Convergence using Comparison

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So we know that the sum  $$ \sum_{n= 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{(n^2 + 1)}$$ is divergent because it is practically the same function as $\dfrac{1}{n}$ which is also divergent.

But what official test tells me this? Ration and root are inconclusive, and I can't do the comparison test because $$\dfrac{n}{(n^2 + 1)} < \dfrac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Do you have to use comparison test? The integral test would also work here because the integration is very easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in fact use the [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test). Let $a_n,b_n\geq 0$, then if

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=C $$
for some $C>0$, then either
$$\sum a_n\quad\text{and}\quad \sum b_n $$
both diverge or converge.

Since
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n/(n^2 + 1)}{1/n}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}=1, $$
and we know that $\sum 1/n$ diverges we know that your given sum diverges as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the numbers wrong for limit comparison!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You saved me. So useful for test tomorrow.

Comment: @user1419623 You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{n}{n^2+1} \geq \dfrac{n}{2n^2} = \dfrac{1}{2n}$$

Answer (score 2):

In fact,

$$\frac n{n^2+1}\ge\frac n{2n^2}=\frac12\frac1n$$